# PHP incrementing instances of values with a separate array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get a tally of different statues in a dataset. I expected this would be simple, I create a `$statuses` array, loop through the data and increment a count for each `status` in my `$statuses`. Here is what I've done:

```
$data = array(
    array('status'=>'a'),
    array('status'=>'b'),
    array('status'=>'c'),
    array('status'=>'c'),
    array('status'=>'c'),
    array('status'=>'c'),
    array('status'=>'c'),
    array('status'=>'c'),
    array('status'=>'c'),
    array('status'=>'b'),
    array('status'=>'b'),
    array('status'=>'a'),
    array('status'=>'a'),
    array('status'=>'a'),
);

$statuses = array();
foreach($data as $row) {
    if(!in_array($row['status'], $statuses)) {                                           
        $statuses[$row['status']] = 0;
    }
    $statuses[$row['status']] += 1;
}

var_dump($statuses);
```

Results in:

```
array(3) { ["a"]=> int(1) ["b"]=> int(1) ["c"]=> int(1) }
```

I can think of a few other ways to accomplish this, but I'm too curious: why aren't my statuses incrementing here? I've also tried a few other methods of incrementing, but it does not matter:

```
$statuses[$row['status']]++;
++$statuses[$row['status']];
$statuses[$row['status']] = $statuses[$row['status']] + 1;
```

It's all the same.

I struggled to search for similar questions to this, most of the results I found are "how do I loop" or otherwise irrelevant. Any help with the title would also be appreciated.

Comment: it's the `in_array($row['status'], $statuses)` that doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: change that to `!isset($statuses[$row['status']])` and it'll work! https://3v4l.org/MLUgK

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the help! I knew I must have been overlooking something, that seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `in_array($row['status'], $statuses)` that doesn't do what you expect (because it searches for values - see @trincot's answer).
You could change the condition to

```
if(!isset($statuses[$row['status']])) { 
    $statuses[$row['status']] = 0;
}
```

and you'll get your desired result:

```
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>int(4)
  ["b"]=>int(3)
  ["c"]=>int(7)
}
```

Fiddle: https://3v4l.org/MLUgK

Answer (score 3):

You can use some built-in functions for that:

```
$result = array_count_values(array_column($data, 'status'));
```

NB: `in_array` will look for *values*, not *keys*. The function to look for *keys* is `array_key_exists`

Comment: Thank you! I was scratching my head, but that makes a lot more sense. I read Jeff and your answers at once, I'm going to accept his answer but it was a difficult choice. No offense, I appreciate the help!